# Splitting an array and counting values

Tags: java

I'm trying to figure out how to implement a method that does the following:

The method takes in a text file and counts the number of words up until a specified character "#".

An array is passed as a parameter through the method, this contains a list of sequential numbers. A number in an array corresponds to the position the word occurs in the text file (disregarding #'s) so the 4th word will correspond to a value of 3 (n-1).

The method will count the number of times the word before a # occurs in the array and divide it by the total number of entries between #'s it will then take the average of each time this is done.

So an example to make this clear:

Say you have the text file containing :

Hi my name # is something #

A corresponding array would be:

0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4,4 (a number for each letter in sequence)

The first hash would occur between the 2 and 3. So the 2's represent the word occuring before the #.  So we would  calculate (total number of 2's)/total number of 0's, 1's and 2's.  This would be 4/9.

We would then calculate the same between the two hashes # is something #. 'something' corresponds to a 4, so we would have (total number of 4's)/total number of 3 and 4's.
This would be 2/3.

We would then take the average of 2/3 and 4/9

I hope this is clear, let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Show us the code that you have.

Comment: Anything you've already tried?

Comment: By solving this for you, it defeats the purpose of the homework...

Comment: Nice, you removed the homework tag

Comment: I never added it in the first place, someone else did

Comment: that's true ^ Jack did: "Probably homework"

Comment: also "my" has two letters, I guess that corresponds to two 1's - not three as you wrote there ^ - and so the total is 4/8, right ?

Comment: I tried to understand what this question is asking, but neither the description or the example make sense to me.  (And I can't see the point of the calculation either.)

Comment: I can't see the point of this calculation either, and don't know what _We would then take the average of 2/3 and 4/9_ means, but .. :/ :S fun I guess..

Answer (score 1):

I'd `split()` the string for any whitespace chars. Now I have every word in an array, with each cell's index representing the corresponding num, and the cell's content(the word) length is the 'how many 0's or 1's or ..' I have.
That should solve the first part of your problem.

Then you need to find where each `#` is, its offset that is, but that offset you want to represent in words, not chars. So I'd iterate through the previously created array, and check if the word I stored is a `#`. If it is I'd update a marker variable (this should hold the previous position/index of the last seen `#`), and calculate the division you want (4/8 , 2/3 w/e). That is the length of the previous cell's content divided by the sum of length's from the marker until the current index-1.

I think that's about it; the logic. It's not that hard to implement. Just don't forget to check the bounds.

Comment: Hi, the word length isnt the number of 0's or 1's its just any random number

Comment: hmm? you said that "name" is 4 letters, and thus four 2's, so the division is 4/total_num_of_nums

Comment: hmm! you didn't say that, but this still works. Instead of the length just get the number of the nums of the corresponding index, and you're done. Same thing.